# file_get_contents() on network fails. Php - windows 7

Tags: php

I've been searching the internet for the solution but I still can't find the answer on copying through file network using php.
Please see my sample code ang its output:

```
<?php
$source = ("file://///server/path/file.txt");
$destination = 'sample.txt';
$data = file_get_contents($source);
$handle = fopen($destination, "w");
if(fwrite($handle, $data)){
echo "success";
fclose($handle);
}
else
{
echo"failed";
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Web output:
failed

destination folder output:
sample.txt with blank contents.

I granted permission to access the file and is available to access using my network. and is using Windows 7 platform
it is very much easy copying a file from your local drive.
what must I do to be able to copy the file from the server?
I even tried `\\(computername/ipaddress)\path\file.txt` but not worth it. I just make use of google for that said code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem might be with `file://///server/path/file.txt`. When I try that kind of url to access a shared drive on the network, chrome shortens to url to `file://server/path/file.txt` (ie, only two slashes, not five).

Comment: Thanks for the concern but does not address the issue.